# IntelliJ Ultimate closes unexpectedly [provided Log]

Tags: intellij-idea

Im using

> IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-182.3684.101, built
>   on July 24, 2018 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK
>   64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Windows 10 10.0

Last month a problem occurs frequently. While I am coding the IDE closes and the progress i have made is not saved. This is really annoying. I have read carefully the log of IDEA and I cannot understand whats the problem. I attach the log file (only the lines that affect the problem). If there is any experience from anyone else who had the same problem please let me know. I have also sent a request to intellij but no aswer so far.

The attached log file lines

```
2018-08-31 19:44:25,283 [1209634]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - START INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2018-08-31 19:44:25,320 [1209671]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - END INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2018-08-31 19:44:25,322 [1209673]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - START StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2018-08-31 19:44:25,323 [1209674]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - END StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2018-08-31 19:44:25,326 [1209677]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose started 
2018-08-31 19:44:25,330 [1209681]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose completed 
2018-08-31 19:44:25,330 [1209681]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------
```

sometimes also this message appears in log but I'm not sure if its relevant:

```
ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction exit code 1
```

Comment: What JDK are you using? Older than OpenJDK 8u92? Can you post the very beginning of your log files, where it specifies the JVM and JRE.

Comment: Unfortunately, the last lines of the log are insufficient - they are quite standard. Any possibility you can upload the whole log?